# Convert key rawRepresentation to x963Representation to create SecKey

Tags: swift, cryptography

Here is a problem with creating P256 `SecKey` for ios 10 for 32 bytes of private key.

There is no problem to use this bytes to create `P256` private key with function from iOS13

```swift
try? P256.Signing.PrivateKey(rawRepresentation: bytes)
```

and then to get x963Representation to create a `SecKey`

But on iOS10 we don't have an ability to use this function... So I have to convert 32 bites key to 97 somehow to represent it in ANSI x9.63 format

Example of key bytes

```
[110, 181, 159, 0, 54, 16, 25, 129, 87, 128, 85, 36, 192, 64, 195, 4, 20, 47, 243, 134, 160, 57, 30, 210, 89, 225, 223, 114, 11, 121, 57, 156]
```

x963Representation

```
[4, 37, 167, 241, 121, 238, 41, 22, 35, 158, 89, 144, 215, 243, 4, 91, 217, 243, 23, 42, 171, 228, 247, 89, 136, 123, 22, 71, 11, 205, 134, 29, 110, 83, 241, 239, 135, 37, 226, 40, 179, 11, 191, 193, 232, 124, 41, 160, 136, 53, 95, 33, 233, 207, 151, 83, 136, 234, 97, 4, 79, 115, 227, 69, 42, 252, 66, 68, 64, 32, 176, 11, 75, 206, 158, 228, 246, 9, 179, 36, 94, 186, 209, 125, 152, 192, 192, 141, 242, 200, 108, 181, 75, 103, 86, 171, 231]
```

I see that x963Representation contains:

header(04) + ? + ? + 32_Private_Key_Bytes

The question is - how to count `x` and `y` to get the key form `(04 || X || Y || K)`  ?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the key derivation. Key derivation is used to construct or derive a **symmetric** key, **not** an asymmetric key. Although the bytes might be long enough to construct a raw key, it is very likely that the symmetric key is not a valid asymmetric key or not a _secure_ asymmetric key

Comment: @Bram Hello. Thank you a lot. Basically private key it's just a set of random bytes. 
Depending on curve we can get different public key (x and y). 
I needed a solution to be able to count these x and y from 32 bytes of initial private key.

Comment: @Bram and you are right that i used incorrectly word "Derivation". ))) I just too unexperienced in cryptography

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question can be resolved with the library https://github.com/Sajjon/EllipticCurveKit/tree/main/Sources/EllipticCurveKit

Just need to get rid from HASH functionality or rewrite it with CommonCrypto library instead of CryptoKit